# Unable to instantiate application proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

when i use proguard it always errors like this. I do not know what to do I have tried all the tutorials. please help anyone who can help.

```
Process: com.example.belajarproguard, PID: 22062
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.belajarproguard.MVVMApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.belajarproguard.MVVMApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5335)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.belajarproguard.MVVMApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5335) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

MVVMApplication

```
class MVVMApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@MVVMApplication))

        bind() from singleton { NetworkConnectionInterceptor(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { BasicAuth() }
        bind() from singleton { MyApi(instance(), instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { MarketingRepo(instance(), instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { AppDatabase(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { PageFragmentsViewModelFactory(instance()) }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show your proguard rules file also the MVVMApplication class

Comment: I haven't entered any rules yet

Comment: I put in the rules -keep class com.example.belajarproguard, 
and nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem has been resolved, the problem is in multidex

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.belajarproguard.MVVMApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.belajarproguard.MVVMApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.belajarproguard-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

You just need to change

```
class MVVMApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {
```

to

```
class MVVMApplication : MultiDexApplication(), KodeinAware {
```

add this to the class

```
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
```

and add this to the dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

source

> [Enable Multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex?hl=eng)

don't forget
clean project before

Answer (score 2):

In your `proguard rules` file, please put below rule:

```
-keep class com.example.belajarproguard.** { *; }
```

OR

if you are using `androidX`, you can use `@Keep` annotation.

```
@Keep
class MVVMApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@MVVMApplication))

        bind() from singleton { NetworkConnectionInterceptor(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { BasicAuth() }
        bind() from singleton { MyApi(instance(), instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { MarketingRepo(instance(), instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { AppDatabase(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { PageFragmentsViewModelFactory(instance()) }
    }

}
```